# Adobe Animate Countdown to a specific date

Tags: javascript

I am having issues loading (browser) the JavaScript assigned to a text field in Adobe Animate CC.

The code is as follows

---

```
var specific_d=new Date(2018, 8, 24);

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick"tickF.bnd(this));

function tickF(){

var d=new Date();

this.countdown_txt.text=Math.round((specific_d.getTime()-d.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24))+" days";

}
```

---

The error messages are (console.log)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AdobeAn is not defined
    at init at onload
```

Comment: Your code is invalid (`"tick"tickF.bnd(this)`). Please improve it.

Comment: Thank you Chayim, any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `"tick", tickF.bnd(this)`.

Comment: Please attach line numbers (to the errors), or say what's the line the error occurred (and the file?)

Comment: Thank you, but still get an error

Uncaught TypeError: tickF.bnd is not a function
    at lib.Untitled1.frame_0 (Untitled-1.js?1534061254022:34)
    at a.b._runActions (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:17)
    at a.b.setPosition (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:17)
    at a.b.setPosition (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:17)

Comment: at lib.Untitled1.c._updateTimeline (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:14)
    at lib.Untitled1.c.advance (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:14)
    at lib.Untitled1.c._tick (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:14)
    at lib.Stage.b._tick (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:13)
    at lib.Stage.b.tick (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:13)
    at lib.Stage.b.update (createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:13)

Comment: Dou you want to use `bind()` of JS, or another function? I think you should write `tickF.bind(this)` (see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

Comment: The stange this now is the countdown is to Sept and not Aug

Comment: You don't show the month!

Comment: I thought I am --- var specific_d=new Date(2018, 8, 10);

Comment: It's just a countdown to the 24 August 2018 e.g 12 DAYS LEFT

Comment: So if I change the date to

var specific_d=new Date(2018, 7, 24); 

It gives me the correct number of days to the 24 August

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why I need to put the due date as 24th July instead of 24th August to get the correct DAYS LEFT

Comment: MDN: "Note: The argument monthIndex is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and December = 11.". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

Comment: Of course... Thank you